# Is it possilbe to add and remove menu items from Blazor's default navmenu while in a webpage?

Tags: blazor

I'm experimenting with Blazor.

I have a table of companies that displays some information about the company and, what I want, is for when a user clicks on one of those rows a new tab will be created on Blazor's default side-nav menu, with further information about the company.

I do not want to automatically be redirected there, I just want the tab to be created. The idea is that the user can just go down the list, selecting the ones they are interested in, which will create new tabs on the side, then be able to go through those tabs one-by-one and only having them destroyed when they choose to destroy them.

Is this possible in Blazor?

Comment: Could you please add the code from your "table of companies"

Comment: If your "tabs" are create in a loop for each it's only add an element to one array